# Silverlight: How to apply an effect to a user control

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a DataGrid and I need to apply an effect to a cell depending on the value of the cell.

Not sure how to do it. I have the effect writen in code but am not sure not to apply it. What i want to end up with is

```
myTextBlock.Effect = myDropShadowEffect;
```

How can i achieve this? Do I first say

If so, how do I define "MyEffect", should MyEffect be a c# class that implements a certain interface and overrides an "Effect" method or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You create an Effect by inheriting off of the `Effect` class or more likely the `ShaderEffect` class.

You can then create a new instance of your Effect class and assign it the Effect property of a control.

(Note if your effect is actually a Drop Shadow Effect there is already a builtin effect for that).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/118965/268552.aspx#268552)

It seems it'll be easier to do in XAML.  Unless you really need it in the code behind.